# While Loops - hidden insert types - get or post?

Tags: php

just got a quick question about while loops and hidden values!

At the moment I am trying to develop a page were I can delete people from a table in the database but before this I want to search for the person and display the results with a delete button after the record. I have the search working! I have even made the delete button, but I need help passing the variable.

I have tried passing a hidden variable like below:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' id='deleted' name='deleted' value = '<?php "echo $finder" ?>'>";
```

That when clicked will pass the variable to the next page where I want it deleted, but I get the following error:

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO, expecting ',' or';')

below is the whole while loop:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Found Person to delete</title>
</head>


<body>

<?php 

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>cust_id</th>";
echo "<th>First Name</th>";
echo "<th>Last Name</th>";
echo "<th>Email</th>";
echo "<th>Delete Record</th>";
echo "</tr>";

include '\../php_includes/db_conx.php';
$finder = $_POST['delete'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE firstname LIKE '%{$finder}%' OR lastname LIKE '%{$finder}%' OR email LIKE '%{$finder}%' OR cust_id LIKE '%{$finder}%'";

$rs = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query);

if($query)
{

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs))
{

echo "<form action= 'delete_final.php' method='POST'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['cust_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><input type ='submit' name = 'delete' value = 'delete'></td>";
echo "<input type='hidden' id='deleted' name='deleted' value = '<?php "echo $finder" ?>'>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
}
echo "</table>";
}

?>


</body>
</html>
```

I guess I want to pass the variable the user had written from the search page, find the user (search which is working) and next to the displayed person have a delete button (which I have), that when clicked will take the variable typed by the user and delete that person.

and to do this I want to use `<input type = 'hidden'>` so that when I click delete it will use the hidden variable (what the user typed) find that user and delete them.

Is this a good way to go about it ? or am I making it more difficult then it should be ?

I was using `GET` in the form before rather then post but same issue.

can I put that input type hidden in the while loop? should be using `GET` rather `POST`? why is it not working ?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using echo in an echo. Try it like this:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" id="deleted" name="deleted" value="' . echo $finder . '"'>';
```

Comment: why not just  .$finder?

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years Because of a copy-paste error. You're obviously right, it has been rectified, thanks!